# Google Apps SAML error app_not_configured_for_user

Tags: laravel, saml

I'm trying to enable SAML for our domain so that Google Apps is our idP
Unfortunately we're getting an error which we can't solve.

```
403. That’s an error.

Error: app_not_configured_for_user

Service is not configured for this user.

Request Details
SAMLRequest=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
RelayState=/
hl=nl
idpid=C017lp46m

That’s all we know.
```

We're building on Laravel 5.2 + the aacotroneo/laravel-saml2 package.

Is anybody familiar with this error?

- Just to be sure, SAML is enabled for this user in Google Apps.

Comment: How did you solve this? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: unfortunately we didn't. Ultimately we've switched to laravel socialite with oAuth

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and it turns out that I had two google apps for work accounts and I had configured the app in the wrong one. As a result, I got this message. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello @denodster … Could you please more clear on the solution ? Thanks.

Comment: I had two gsuite accounts, one for domain1.com and the other for domain2.com I was attempting to configure the app for domain1.com while setting it up in the control panel for domain2.com. @KrithikaVittal

Comment: Oh got it ... Thanks !!! I  made the same mistake and fixed it.